# TextWatcher is preveting delete whole string from EditText, just char to char

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, masking, textwatcher

I have one Editext that use a TextWatcher, to make an Currency Mask.

Is working fine, but when i try to delete text, pressing and holding backspace from soft-keyboard, the text isn't erased, unless i repeated press the key multiple times.

I think that can be because every text change, i have to call setText, and this is messing the flow.

Any suggestion ?

```
    myEditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                                   before: Int, count: Int) {

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                                       count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
            myEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this)

            val parsed = parseToBigDecimal(editable.toString(), locale)
            val formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).format(parsed)

            myEditText.setText(formatted)
            myEditText.setSelection(formatted.length)
            myEditText.addTextChangedListener(this)

        }
    })



private fun parseToBigDecimal(value: String, locale: Locale): BigDecimal {
    val replaceable = String.format("[%s,.\\s]", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).currency.symbol)

    val cleanString = value.replace(replaceable.toRegex(), "")

    return BigDecimal(cleanString).setScale(
            2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR).divide(BigDecimal(100), BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of these methods you can detect whether text is removed. You can then set a flag to skip/handle/differentiate whatever is in `afterTextChanged`.

```
    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                               before: Int, count: Int) {

    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                                   count: Int, after: Int) {
    }
```

Comment: I can't, because every change, even is erasing something, i need to adjust the money mask